# Response cache not working in asp.net core project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-core

I try to implement Response cache in asp.net core project but its not working.This is `startup.cs`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
  services.AddResponseCaching();
  services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) 
{
    app.UseResponseCaching();

    if (env.IsDevelopment()) 
    {
      app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
```

And this is my controller.

```cs
[ResponseCache(Duration = 30)]
public IActionResult Index() 
{
  ViewBag.IsMobile = RequestExtensions.IsMobileBrowser(ContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request);
  return View();
}
```

But still cache control header id

```
cache-control →no-cache, no-store
```

Where I am lacking please help. This response cache is not working and I take guidance from Microsoft document.

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? Try to make a test with CacheController [https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/blob/master/MVCPro/Controllers/CacheController.cs#L12] to check whether it is related with your environment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Beware that for the cache to work must meet a number of requirements:

> The request must result in a 200 (OK) response from the server.
>
> The request method must be GET or HEAD.
>
> Terminal middleware, such as Static File Middleware, must not process
>   the response prior to the Response Caching Middleware.
>
> The Authorization header must not be present.
>
> Cache-Control header parameters must be valid, and the response must
>   be marked public and not marked private.
>
> The Pragma: no-cache header/value must not be present if the
>   Cache-Control header is not present, as the Cache-Control header
>   overrides the Pragma header when present. The Set-Cookie header must
>   not be present.
>
> Vary header parameters must be valid and not equal to *.
>
> The Content-Length header value (if set) must match the size of the
>   response body.
>
> ...

See this website: [aspnet-core-response-cache](https://dzone.com/articles/aspnet-core-response-cache)

And beware also that if the request is being made from Postman disable the option "do not send the cache header".

See this post (image of end post):  [ASP.Net Core 2.0 - ResponseCaching Middleware - Not Caching on Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48232911/asp-net-core-2-0-responsecaching-middleware-not-caching-on-server)

Comment: thanks for this sanmolhec, the vary header and postman tip really helped me out

Answer (score 4):

To set up response caching in dotnet core follow these steps:

1. In Startup.cs locate the `ConfigureServices` method and add the following line:

   services.AddResponseCaching();
2. Ins Startup.cs locate the `Configure` method and add the following lines:

   ```
       app.UseResponseCaching();

       app.Use(async (context, next) =>
       {
           context.Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl =
               new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue()
               {
                   Public = true,
                   MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
               };
           context.Response.Headers[Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.Vary] =
               new string[] { "Accept-Encoding" };

           await next();
       });
   ```
3. Apply the `[ResponseCache]` attribute to the action which requires caching:

   ```
   [ResponseCache(Duration = 300, VaryByQueryKeys = new string[] { "id" })]
   [HttpGet]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int id)
   {
       return View();
   }
   ```

Comment: Can you please take a look at the question I posted?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72755972/netcore-responsecache-does-not-work-for-some-routes

Answer (score 2):

I tried [this Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and successfully cached.

```
Cache-Control: public,max-age=30
Date: Thu, 27 Dec 2018 07:50:16 GMT
```

I think you are missing the `app.Use(async => )` part.

Comment: after adding this as well,its not showing any cache control

Answer (score 1):

There are a few steps to getting the ResponseCaching to function:

1. You need to call `AddResponseCaching()` and `UseResponseCaching()` in Startup.cs correctly
2. The page must **return** a Cache-Control header e.g. `Cache-Control: public,max-age=60` (Note that it MUST contain the `public` directive). You can do this via the `[ResponseCache]` attribute, manually adding it to the response headers, etc.
3. Method must be GET or HEAD, status code must be 200
4. Authorization request header must **not** be present
5. If the client sends up their own cache-control header in the request, it must be valid - i.e. if the client passes up `Cache-Control: max-age=0` (which Chrome/Firefox/etc do if the user presses F5) then the response will never be served from the cache because anything cached is by definition older than 0 seconds
6. Various other conditions. I recommend making sure you can see debug-level logs from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.ResponseCachingMiddleware` which will output the reason it isn't caching the request

In my case, I wanted to ignore the client request Cache-Control header, so I added a subclass of `ResponseCachingPolicyProvider` like so:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// By default, <see cref="ResponseCachingPolicyProvider"/> will not return a cached response
    /// if the client sends up a Cache-Control header indicating the client wants a fresh
    /// response. This is according to HTTP spec but is not the behavior we want, so
    /// we will remove the client's specified Cache-Control header while evaluating whether
    /// or not we should return the cached response for this request.
    /// </summary>
    public class CustomResponseCachingPolicyProvider : ResponseCachingPolicyProvider
    {
        public override bool IsCachedEntryFresh(ResponseCachingContext context)
        {
            var reqCacheControl = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl];
            context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Remove(HeaderNames.CacheControl);
            var result = base.IsCachedEntryFresh(context);
            context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.CacheControl, reqCacheControl);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

If the request is being served from the memory cache, it will add an `Age` header to the response which you can check to verify the caching is functioning as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Must your action is **GET method**

Add `HttpGet` attribute for your action

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 30)]
[HttpGet] // <---- 
public IActionResult Index() 
{
  ViewBag.IsMobile = RequestExtensions.IsMobileBrowser(ContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request);
  return View();
}
```

Comment: GET is the default http verb in controller actions and is optional